# What is the optimal disposition of coil to maximize the magnetic field created?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

I am trying to create a powerful magnetic field using coil, and possibly some ferromagnetic metal bars.

[image: Examples of magnet disposition]

The white box with the X on it, is empty, or made of air.

Saying that I have no limits on how many metal bars I have, or their dimensions, but I have limited copper wire length that I can use, and through all examples, the current that I use is constant.

The examples in the image included, but I would gladly accept anything new you can think of, what is the best way to have the maximum possible magnetic flux go through the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this - a stack of bars in parallel to the direction you want for the field, above and below the box:

[image]

Since you have limited wire, you want to wrap the largest possible amount of metal bars: the ratio circumference / area gets better as the thing you wrap is larger. But there is no point to make it larger than the area of the box.

Comment: Could you give me any hints on how to calculate the field in the center of the box? All I know is the flux and magnetic field inside the two solenoids with iron cores, but how can I get the mesure of the box part?

Answer (score 0):

having more metal bars wont really effect the magnetic flux as magnetic flux is related to the magnetic field and the area of the loop.As long as the current through the bars is constant the magnetic field will be constant and so will be the flux. one thing you could possibly do to vary the magnetic flux would be to use use a rotating device to change the angle between the magnetic field and the area which will result in a change of magnetic flux